# How can I execute command on startup (rc.local alternative) on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, systemd

I am setting up quota on my Linode server running Ubuntu 16.10, and I get the following error

> Cannot stat() mounted device /dev/root: No such file or directory

So to fix this, I reached [this thread](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=64369#p64369) for the fix which is done by adding

```
ln -s /dev/xvda /dev/root
/etc/init.d/quota restart
```

to the `/etc/rc.local`. But Ubuntu 16.10 doesn't uses `rc.local` anymore instead uses [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd). What is the alternative for `rc.local`, How can I run the above commands on startup?

Also I enabled the service using `systemctl enable rc-local.service` but it didn't work for me. Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: di you run it as root, and did you restart your system?

Comment: @George yes, I did both

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/846212/no-rc-local-in-16-10-so-how-can-i-add-a-command-to-set-brightness-on-boot)

Comment: @George That's not working as well

Comment: Just saw this hack, see if it flies...

Comment: Just tested my answer and updated it, please try and let me know how it goes...

Comment: The quota package should not be looking for `/dev/root`.  Fix the underlying bug and then you don't need to make this symlink.  It should be configured to turn on quotas for all filesystems listed in /etc/fstab ( by uuid preferably ) with the quota option.

Comment: @psusi what should I use instead of `/dev/root`? I am setting up using this https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-perfect-server-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/2/#g0.0.16

Comment: @psusi The problem seems specifically with linode https://licensecart.com/plugin/support_manager/knowledgebase/view/270/quotas-are-off-on-linode-xen-vps/5/

Comment: Does your /etc/fstab file mention /dev/root?  It shouldn't.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### Intro

I think you should not create a new service as suggested in the link by George.
The `rc-local.service` already exists in systemd and the service file suggests that the `rc.local`, if it exists and is executable, **gets pulled automatically into `multi-user.target`**.
So no need to recreate or force something that is just done in another way by the `systemd-rc-local-generator`.

### One solution

A quick solution (I don't know if that's the canonical way):

In a terminal do:

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
sudo reboot
```

After that the `rc.local` will be called upon system startup. Insert what you like.

### Background

If you do in a terminal:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full rc-local
```

You can see that the head comment contains lines such as:

```
# This unit gets pulled automatically into multi-user.target by
# systemd-rc-local-generator if /etc/rc.local is executable.
```

This indicates, that in this system, if there is a file called `/etc/rc.local` which is executable, then it will be pulled into multi-user.target automatically. So you just create the according file (`sudo touch...`) and make it executable (`sudo chmod +x ...`).

Comment: Don't use `#!/bin/bash` though, use `#!/bin/sh` unless you really need bash in your script. All other system scripts use dash, not bash, for performance reasons.

Comment: "no need to recreate or force something that is just done in another way by the systemd-rc-local-generator" `rc-local` doesn't allow to order it after some other unit, is it not?

Comment: Must `exit 0` be listed as last command in `/etc/rc.local` ?

Answer (score 24):

I saw this solution suggested which involves use of `systemd` [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd):

1. Create a service:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
   ```
2. Add your code there:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
   ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
   TimeoutSec=0
   StandardOutput=tty
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   SysVStartPriority=99

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Create and make sure `/etc/rc.local` is executable and add this code inside it:

   > `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   #
   # rc.local
   #
   # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
   # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
   # value on error.
   #
   # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
   # bits.
   #
   # By default this script does nothing.

   exit 0
   ```
4. Enable the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable rc-local
   ```
5. Start service and check status:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start rc-local.service
   sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
   ```
6. If all goes well you can add your `code` to the `/etc/rc.local` file then restart it.

**Note:** Tested on Lubuntu 16.10.

Source:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd

Comment: I did all the steps. I have the rc.local with: `touch "hello"` before the `exit 0`. The service seems to be active but it does not create any file in the /etc/ dir Running on ubuntu 16.04 Arabian 5.31

Comment: As the the answer by @Jan points out, creating a whole new service is not necessary as systemd supports rc.local already.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu, this just works

Answer (score 7):

To add to [Jan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/681688) that, unlike the usual `rc.local`file, `rc-local service` is executed not after all services have been started, but after the network goes online.

In some cases you may want to run commands from `rc.local` later. 
For example, I wanted it to be executed after `lxd` start.

In this case you can edit `rc-local service` startup dependencies by creating a drop-in conf file:
`/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d/override.conf`
with contents:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target lxd.service
```

Where you can add a needed unit name (like I added `lxd.service`)

Do not forget to `systemctl daemon-reload` after that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you want to improve another answer please suggest an edit to it. If you want present a partial alternative please repeat or quote the parts that are the same (in case the original answer changes) and highlight the differences. In any case don’t create a new *incomplete* answer! Thank you.