# Ubuntu Server 17.04 enable numlock without desktop environment

Tags: server, virtualbox, 16.10, 17.04, numlock

In earlier Ubuntu versions I would [do](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock):

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*$|# Numlock enable\n[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] \&\& numlockx on\n\nexit 0|' /etc/rc.local
```

But starting from version 16.10 there is no file `rc.local`, so how to I enable numlock in version 17.04 **without desktop environment**?

***Update:*** I created `rc.local` file as described https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/158442, then executed commands mentioned earlier and now numpad works when I connect over SSH. For it to work in VirtualBox I added [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock) lines to `rc.local`:

```
# Turn Numlock on for the TTYs:
for tty in /dev/tty[1-6]; do
    /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < $tty
done
```

And now everything works!

Comment: Possible, but I do not want to replicate `rc.local` functionality, there were reasons it was removed, I just want to be able to use my numpad :)

Comment: You don't need to replicate anything. See https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/158442. Since `rc.local` is run if it exists and is executable, and the default `rc.local` never did anything, obviously there's no need to keep it in the default. Anybody who wants to use simply needs to create it.

Comment: ok, I tried that, but when I do `sudo printf '#!/bin/bash\nexit 0' > /etc/rc.local` I get error Permission denied...

Comment: That would be because of https://askubuntu.com/q/230476/158442. I fixed those commands in an edit just now.

Comment: Thank You @muru, numpad now works when I connect over SSH, but it still does not work when typing in the computer itself (I have it running in a VirtualBox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created `rc.local` file as suggested by @muru and described at https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/158442, then executed commands mentioned earlier and now numpad works when I connect over SSH.

For it to work in VirtualBox I added [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock) lines to `rc.local`:

```
# Turn Numlock on for the TTYs:
for tty in /dev/tty[1-6]; do
    /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < $tty
done
```

And after reboot everything works!