# Mapping shared folder on Ubuntu server guest through rc.local

Tags: virtualbox, automount

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 17.04 (Guest) on VBox (Win 10 as host). I have set shared folder and try to automount it. Now, when I run manually the command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf src /media/src
```

Everything works fine, I have the folder mounted and all the files visible/editable. So I have put this command into `/etc/rc.local` and restart the machine. And the folder doesn't show up... I have set the service according to [these instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/886631) and still nothing. I checked service status by `systemctl status rc-local.service` and got following result:

```
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-09-10 18:45:10 CEST; 14min ago
  Process: 1185 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/rc-local.service

Sep 10 18:45:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Sep 10 18:45:10 ubuntu sudo[1192]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mount -t vboxsf src /media/src
Sep 10 18:45:10 ubuntu sudo[1192]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 10 18:45:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

So it seems everything's fine. What's more interesting I added the simple `touch` instruction to test that rc/local is actually run so now the file is as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

touch /home/moby/dupa.zbita.kurwa.jego.mac

sudo mount -t vboxsf src /media/src

exit 0
```

Now, the file is beeing created so the file runs, yet the folder is not mounted as I expect. I thought that I made a typo in mount command but when I run the `/etc/rc.local` manually (obviously it is executable) the folder appears properly.

What should I do to make this work? Of course I could enable mount command to run without password from my user and add the command into ¬/.bashrc file to make it work for now (or simply run the mount by hand) but I am wondering what's wrong and how to fix it anyway...

[edit]
[image: Screen [2]] asked in comment:

Comment: Let me understand you, you want that folder to be auto-mounted when Ubuntu guest boots up, if so please go to shared folders settings on virtualbox and set that folder to `Make-Permanent`

Comment: @George: The options I have in Virtual Box are `auto-mount` (which I checked) and `read-only` (which I don't want). But yes, I want that folder to be automounted somehow...

Comment: Then pick `auto-mount` that's what you want!

Comment: @George: As I said, I already have this option checked and still I need to run `mount -t (...)` command to get access to the directory (or maybe it's available somewhere else and I miss it?)

Comment: Please give me a screen shot if that's possible.

Comment: Added in edit - is this what you asked for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65430/discussion-between-moby04-and-george).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the benefits of using Virtualbox is ability to add `guest-additions` to the host making it possible to interact seamlessly between host and guest OSes.

To set this up add the guest additions via either the command line for Virtualbox installs using the official repo, or from the oracle site if using `.deb` files to install.

Now to setup folder sharing we need to:

1. Add the guest additions as mentioned earlier
2. Add the desired folder from:

   - virtualbox settings menu for the guest OS in question, or

     [image]
   - from the the `devices` menu from the launched `VM`

     [image]

     [image]
3. Select the options:

   - `Auto-Mount` and `Make -Permanent`
4. In the guest Ubuntu OS add your user to the group `vboxsf`:

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $USER
   ```
5. Restart Ubuntu so the new group addition gets picked up
6. And note the convention is to name the folder with a "sf_" so look for a file named like so `sf_********` in the `/media` folder. Example: `/media/sf_vbox_share`

You don't need to manually mount that shared folder, that's what `Virtualbox Guest Additions` are for.