# Disabling Touchpad on Startup; rc.local Not Working

Tags: touchpad, startup

On xfce, I can just do it in the settings, but I am trying to switch to i3.

Running this command when I am booted disables the touchpad effectively:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
```

I am on Ubuntu 17.10 so I did not find rc.local in /etc/.

I looked around and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886620/how-can-i-execute-command-on-startup-rc-local-alternative-on-ubuntu-16-10) solution on stackexchange which reenables rc.local on systemd.

So, I followed it and added the above command to rc.local which now exists.

However, my touchpad is not being disabled so I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting

```
exec --no-startup-id xinput --disable "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

into i3 config seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the touchpad on boot up by creating a `.desktop` entry in your `/.config/autostart/` directory.

In order to perform that, follow the below steps.

First we need to create the desktop entry in `.config/autostart/` in the home directory of our user using the following command.

`touch /home/<user>/.config/autostart/touchpad.desktop` (file name is optional)

then we need to add entries in the file and make the file executable.

```
vim /home/<user>/.config/autostart/touchpad.desktop
```

and paste the following in that file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Disable touchpad
GenericName=Touchpad disabler
Comment=Disables touchpad
Exec=xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=touchpad.desktop
```

save the file and exit the editor.

And make it executable using the following steps

```
chmod 755 /home/<user>/.config/autostart/touchpad.desktop
```

Reboot and check. Your touch pad would be disabled in your  login.

To enable tocuhpad after disabling it, you may run the following in a terminal.

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 1
```

Note that this would enable touchpad only for the current session. You have to remove the desktop entry or change the value from `0` to `1` in order to enable the touchpad on boot up.

***If you want to disable the touchpad only and not the physical buttons (Left and right click), then***

replace `Exec=xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0` to

```
Exec=synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

Comment: The script works, but adding it to crontab doesn't seem to make it execute on boot, unless I did something wrong.

Comment: @Vpie649 Please try the new method which i have edited in the answer.

Comment: @ran I did exactly what you have suggested but it doesnt work for me (Xubuntu), although the turn off command works just fine in the shell.