# rc.local file is missing in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: scripts, kubuntu

I tried to edit my rc.local file in order to use a script with parameters on startup but it doesnt exist. I am using Kubuntu 18.04. Has it been removed?

Comment: Did you checked this thread? https://askubuntu.com/questions/886620/how-can-i-execute-command-on-startup-rc-local-alternative-on-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: Thank you ! Didn't imagine it would be so simple..

Comment: @Fabby the problem is already solved by Bardyl.

Comment: Yup.  but if another person drops by with the same problem as you, they will clearly see where to go without reading all of the comments.  That's what "Duplicate"  means: better Google search results.  **;-)**