# Restore screen brightness automatically at boot

Tags: nvidia, brightness, 19.04

I want to run this script on ubuntu 19.04, after booting the OS to restore the previous screen brightness:

```
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
```

How can I run this script so it takes effect at the right moment?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I solved this problem [by creating a cron job](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd):

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and including this line at the end of the file:

```
@reboot (sleep 2 ; echo 80 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness) &
```

I found that 2 seconds was enough time to override Nvidia's reset timing at boot. You can adjust the brightness level (80) to your own preference.

PS: Just found out that an additional fix is needed: even though the code above fixes brightness at boot, it won't do it when the computer wakes up from sleep/hibernation, Nvidia resets brightness to max again. To fix this, create in addition the following script in a file in the /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 action="$1"
 case $1 in
   post)
     echo 80 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
     ;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a script  eg brightness.sh. , with #!/bin/bash at the top (not sure if this is necessary) make it executable (right click, permissions, executable) , then put that in startup applications - Power Key then type startup, select Startup applications, add button, type (<> are your particular locations)

```
bash "/home/<username>/<MySctipts>/brightness.sh"
```

Comment: That doesn't work because you don't have root access which is required to write brightness.

Comment: what if it is run by sudo bash ....sh    ? hassle to put in password though.

Answer (score 0):

Your system may be setup to automatically restore the last brightness setting already. You can however edit `/etc/rc.local` and insert this line before `exit 0` at the bottom:

```
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
```

Note you can also use `cron@reboot` if `rc.local-service` isn't setup in `systemd`:

- [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 doesn't use rc.local also I have tried creating the file properly with exit 0 and all of that and doesn't work.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/886620/how-can-i-execute-command-on-startup-rc-local-alternative-on-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: Try the second answer which sets up service file as described in my link. Cron@reboot is another option and you might find that a better fit.

Comment: I need to run the command AFTER the reboot not before, are you sure cron@reboot does that properly? How do I add the line?