# Non-UI differences between Ubuntu versions

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, versions, history-of-ubuntu, changelog

I want to know the differences between Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04, not graphical differences, but technical differences like this:

- In Ubuntu 16.04 the file `/etc/rc.local` isn't necessary but in Ubuntu 14.04 it is.

Where can I find information about these changes?

Comment: See the 16.04 Release Notes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/16.04#New_features_in_16.04_LTS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### *Upstart* was replaced with *systemd*.

As a system administrator or power user, many (though not all) of the changes you will observe when upgrading or migrating from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS are due to **which [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) is used.** This includes the specific change you've mentioned where `/etc/rc.local` is no longer present or used by default.

- **14.04 LTS used [Upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart_(software)).** It was not the last release that did, but it was the last LTS release that did.
- **16.04 LTS uses [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)**, as do all currently supported Ubuntu releases.

For general information about why this change was made and what the practical differences are, see:

- ["Losing Graciously"](https://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316)
- [SystemdForUpstartUsers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)
- [Rationale for switching from upstart to systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613366/rationale-for-switching-from-upstart-to-systemd)

For even more general information, you can read release notes (which is a good idea). Potentially the release notes of all intervening releases could be useful for you to read, but I particularly suggest:

- [**Ubuntu 16.04 LTS release notes**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes) (the release you've moved to)
- [Ubuntu 15.04 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes) (when [systemd replaced Upstart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management))

---

**Regarding `/etc/rc.local` specifically**, you may want to look at other mechanisms systemd provides to allow you to define services that run on startup and do what you need done, but you *can* have systemd run the commands in `/etc/rc.local`.

The typical way to make systemd use `/etc/rc.local` is to enable the `rc-local` service, which is provided for compatibility. **As explained in [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)**, you can check if it is already enabled with:

```
sudo systemctl status rc-local
```

You can enable it with:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

The file needs to exist and be marked executable. If you encounter problems, such as the service not being able to start, or if you want more details on how that service works, see:

- [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)
- [How can I execute command on startup (rc.local alternative) on Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886620/how-can-i-execute-command-on-startup-rc-local-alternative-on-ubuntu-16-10)
  (largely applies to earlier and later releases as well)

Comment: Thanks !! I'm going to read the information